# Unable to do brew update- Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew failed

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

I have noticed that I cannot do `brew update`- it gives me this error readout:

```
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cas, skipping update!
rm: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES: is a directory
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.sh: line 708: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES: Is a directory
rm: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES: is a directory
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew failed!
```

I've already tried to do a `brew install git`, but it gives me the same issue. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

For anybody having the same or similar issue, try typing `brew update-reset`on the terminal, and after the process finishes, type `brew update`. It should work.